# Selecting drop down in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to select a option from the drop down. The code is like below

```
<select id="hidBrokerId" name="hidBrokerId" style="display: none;">
<option value="" selected="selected">-- Valitse --</option>
<span class="select-sub" style="display: none; left: 0px; top: 50px; width:232px;">
<span data-value="" style="background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(232, 232, 232);">-- Valitse --</span>
<span data-value="23" style="background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(255, 255, 255);">Mainos netissä</span> </select>
```

Comment: I want to select the option Mainos netissä

Comment: updated answer plz check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is having `display:none` attribute so you need to you actions class to navigate to that element and find it.

```
WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='hidBrokerId' and contains(@style,'display: none')]"));
Actions act = new Actions(driver);
act.moveToElement(ele).click(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//option[contains(text(),'Mainos netissä')]"))).build().perform();
```

Let me know if this works

Comment: Can you please post your html correctly? I see it is having `style='display-none`

Comment: <div class="field text">
<label for="hidBrokerId">Kuulin Freedom Rahoituksesta *</label>
<select id="hidBrokerId" name="hidBrokerId" style="display: none;">
<option value="">-- Valitse --</option>
<option label="Mainos netissä" value="23">Mainos netissä</option>

Comment: Hi nitin, error shoeing when running the script as "Must provide a location for a move action."